# Проход красно-черного дерева в ширину, по уровням

Tags: java, дерево

Нигде не могу найти реализацию прохода по красно-черному дереву на java. Мне это необходимо для записи сбалансированного дерева. Суть задания в чтении файла и записи слов в черные узлы, а номер строки в которой появлялось это слово записать в виде красных листьев этих узлов. Проход нужен, как я думаю, для записи повторений, например если слово участвовало в тексте 3 раза, то 1 вставка проходит дерево в поиске узла с таким словом и так как не находит, то создает новый node и записывает в leftChild номер строки, 2 и далее вставки этого же слова должна сначала пройти по дереву и если находит этот узел, то проверяет rightChild на пустоту, если пустой вставляет в него, если нет, то создает новый node и вставляет в leftChild.

Node.java

```
public class Node {

String iData;
Node leftChild;
Node rightChild;
boolean blackColor;

}
```

Также этот метод будет основой для вывода дерева в консоль, слова будут в алфавитном порядке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

null узлы нужны для возможности создания сбалансированного дерева

Comment: **Нигде не могу найти реализацию прохода по красно-черному дереву на java. Мне это необходимо для записи сбалансированного дерева. ** Обход нужен для уже созданного дерева. Нужно  определиться что Вам все-таки необходимо -- создать дерево или обойти уже созданное. А потом уже искать.

Comment: Я думал так, чтобы создать сбалансированое дерево необходимо искать место для вставки, а исходя из гифки статьи в википедии, метод прохода перебирает каждый узел на уровне. Если идти по черным узлам, чтобы найти место для вставки нового узла, то должен пригодится алгоритм этого прохода подереву. То есть проход будет осуществляться перед каждой новой вставкой нового черного узла. Или я где-то ошибаюсь?

Comment: Ну при чём тут вставка и "Проход красно-черного дерева в ширину, по уровням". ? Обход в ширину он одинаковый что для красно-черного дерева, что для любого др. дерева поиска . В общем обход в ширину тут не в тему.

Comment: Хорошо, а каким тогда способом лучше искать место для вставки, чтобы в конце вышло сбалансированое дерево?